# Netmiko FileTransfer with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco, cisco-ios

I am working on a script to transfer some files to a Cisco IOS device using netmiko FileTransfer. Below is the code that I found to accomplish this.  However I cant seem to find where the source_file should be or how to specify where on the host that files lives. How do I specify where to copy that file from?

```
dest_file_system = 'disk0:/'
source_file = 'test1.txt' # where should this file be live?
dest_file = 'test1.txt'

with FileTransfer(ssh_conn, source_file=source_file, dest_file=dest_file,
file_system=dest_file_system) as scp_transfer:

if not scp_transfer.check_file_exists():
   if not scp_transfer.verify_space_available():
      raise ValueError("Insufficient space available on remote device")

        print("\nTransferring file\n")
        scp_transfer.transfer_file()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file from the scripts perspective if you simple want to call it by name should be in the same directory as the script itself. If you want to move the file to a new directory the search path in the script is relative to the directory the script is run from. Example 1 - The file_name.txt is in the same directory as your script In your script simply call the file source = "file_name.txt". Example 2 create test_folder in current directory that holds your script and call it test_folder move the file_name.txt into test_folder. In your script your source variable would no need to look like this source = "test_folder/file_name.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, till now you found the solution already. If not then You can try the netmiko file transfer feature also. That will be a more secure and efficient way to do it.

try below sample script.

```
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import ConnectHandler, file_transfer

password = getpass()

cisco = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "cisco1.twb-tech.com",
    "username": "pyclass",
    "password": password,
}

source_file = "test1.txt"
dest_file = "test1.txt"
direction = "put"
file_system = "flash:"

ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
transfer_dict = file_transfer(
    ssh_conn,
    source_file=source_file,
    dest_file=dest_file,
    file_system=file_system,
    direction=direction,
    overwrite_file=True,
)

print(transfer_dict)
```